# Room Relation Specify Column Names When Extending

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I am working with some datasets in my room database, and my method is to have one table with information about a dataset called `DatasetInfo` which stores things like name, type of value stored, id, etc; and a second table where I store the values in 3 columns: (id, date, value). This ordered triplet is defined as a `DatasetValue` entity. Here, (date, value) is an ordered pair that I want to plot.

To plot these ordered pairs, I have to convert them to a list of `Entry` objects, where `Entry` takes the values `x` and `y`. It makes the most sense to query my database and simply ask for `List<Entry>`, because right now I ask for `List<DatasetValue>` and then I have to map that result to `List<Entry>` which is unnecessary.

I query for the dataset information table `DatasetInfo` as follows:

```
data class DatasetWithValues(
    @Embedded
    var datasetInfo: DatasetInfo,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = DATASET_COLUMN_DATASET_ID,
        entityColumn = VALUES_COLUMN_ID,
        entity = DatasetValue::class,
    )
    var values : List<Entry>
)
```

Now, as I said above, `Entry` has values `x` and `y`, and `Dataset` calls them `date` and `value`. Of course, when I ask for this relation, it will fail because it doesn't know how to assign values from a table with the columns `id`, `date`, and `value` to an object which takes `x` and `y`. So, I define a new class:

```
class DatasetEntry(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date") 
    var date : Float,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "value") 
    val value : Float
) : Entry(date, value)
```

and then make the following adjustment:

```
//var values : List<Entry>
var values : List<DatasetEntry>
```

That does nothing. The code doesn't compile because:

> SQL error or missing database (no such column: x)

Well, what if I instead write:

```
class DatasetEntry(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    var date : Float,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "value")
    val value : Float
) : Entry(){
    init{
        x = date
        y = value
    }
}
```

That doesn't help either, same error. Even if I remove that `init` call, it still wants `x`.

The plot thickens, because inside of `Entry` I can see `x` is declared private. So I have absolutely no clue what is happening here. How does Room even know to look for `x`? Is there any work around for this other than renaming the columns in my table to `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any work around for this other than renaming the columns in my table to x and y?

If you have such option it would be the easiest. Still there are some options you could consider:

**1. Mapping Room's result to needed one**

So, you ask Room for some `raw` result and then map it to `ready` one. For that you add 2 classes:

```
data class DatasetWithValuesRaw(
    @Embedded
    var datasetInfo: DatasetInfo,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = DATASET_COLUMN_DATASET_ID,
        entityColumn = VALUES_COLUMN_ID,
    )
    var values : List<DatasetValue>
)

data class DatasetWithValuesReady(
    var datasetInfo: DatasetInfo,
    var values : List<Entry>
)
```

Let's say you have a dao method:

```
Query("select * ....")
fun getRawData(): List<DatasetWithValuesRaw>
```

For mapping you use:

```
fun getReadyData() = 
   getRawData().map { item -> 
    DatasetWithValuesReady(item.datasetInfo, 
       item.values.map { Entry(x = it.date, y = it.value) 
   }) }
```

**2. Replacing Room's @Relation with explicit query**

It's not what you really want, but still is an option.
Use class like that:

```
data class DatasetWithSeparateValues(
    @Embedded
    var datasetInfo: DatasetInfo,
    @Embedded
    var value : Entry // <----- it's not a list, just a single value
)
```

and in your dao you set query with explicit columns' names (`x` and `y`). Something like that:

```
Query("SELECT *, values.date as x, values.value as y FROM dataset LEFT JOIN values on dataset.DATASET_COLUMN_DATASET_ID = values.VALUES_COLUMN_ID")
fun getData(): List<DatasetWithSeparateValues>
```

As a result you'll get a list, but if there is a one dataset with 5 values you'll get inside list 5 items with the same dataset and separate values. After that you could use Kotlin collection's methods (`groupBy` for example) to prettify result in some way